# Computing Checksum of byte[] in Java with expected result

Tags: java, ascii, checksum

I need some help with a problem that I just cannot solve. What I have to do is calculate the Checksum of a known byte[]. Lets start with the known values:

I must convert an 8 digit value to 8 bytes of ASCII:

```
Value = 33053083
Converted (asciiValue) = 33:33:30:35:33:30:38:33
```

This is correct, as it matches the expected value given to me.

Next, I need to "Compute the checksum of the ASCII value (asciiValue). Extract the last 2 digits (right justified). The result is the 'Checksum'."

I know the value of this computed checksum is supposed to be 99.

I've looked everywhere and tried just about everything, but I cannot come up with the expected value of 99.

Thank you for the help!

Edited to add given algorithm (in C):

```
unsigned char
vls_byteSum(char *blk, int len)
{
   int i;
   unsigned char sum = 0;
   for (i=0; i < len; ++i)
      sum += blk[i];
      return sum;
}
```

Comment: Checksums can be calculated with lots of different algorithm. Which one are you trying to implement?

Comment: My apologies. The only information I was given was some C code: `unsigned char
vls_byteSum(char *blk, int len)
{
int i;
unsigned char sum = 0;
for (i=0; i < len; ++i)
sum += blk[i];
return sum;
}`

Comment: So what does your version of that C code look like in Java? Show us what you've done.

Comment: Do not forget that a `byte` value in java is _always signed_: Values over 127 are interpreted as negatives.

Comment: The closest I came to interpreting the C code was this: `char sum = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < asciiValue.length; i++){
    sum += (char)asciiValue[i];
   }`

Comment: Change `char` to `byte` and you got it. If you get `-103`, you got the right result. `-103` (signed) = `153` (unsigned) = `0x99` (hex)

Comment: @Andreas PERFECT! Thank you so much! Please add your solution so I may accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you posted in a comment is pretty much correct, except change `char` to `byte`:

```
public static byte vls_byteSum(byte[] blk) {
    byte sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < blk.length; i++)
        sum += blk[i];
    return sum;
}
```

Test it with this:

```
byte result = vls_byteSum(new byte[] { 0x33, 0x33, 0x30, 0x35, 0x33, 0x30, 0x38, 0x33 });
System.out.printf("0x%02x = %d = %d", result, result, Byte.toUnsignedInt(result));
```

Output:

```
0x99 = -103 = 153
```

Comment: so that was meant with 99

Answer (score 1):

The following code should do it for you.

```
public static int checkSum(byte[] input) {
   int checkSum = 0;
   for(byte b : input) {
      checkSum += b & 0xFF;
   }
   return checkSum;
}
```

The `b & 0xFF` converts the byte to an integer and gives it it's unsigned value, that means 255 will be interpreted as 255 instead of -1.

Comment: It doesn't *have* a return type

Comment: Returns the value 409

Comment: This gave me a result of 409.

Comment: Anything but int makes little sense, because that would overflow pretty quickly and OP would need to & 0xFF the output before printing it to console, if it was greater than 127, also this is pretty much the C code in java.

Comment: How do you know the output should be 99 ? And you can change the type to byte if that's what oyu need, but then you will have to 0xFF the value before printing if you want it unsigned.